# Custom Radio Buttons Android Sizing

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, size

Previously, I created a shape drawable ring that was supposed to act as the unchecked version of a custom radio button. I'm seeing that this may not be the best way to do this, and I may need to create an unchecked and a checked version in an external program such as inkscape or photoshop.  I have tried to create them in photoshop, placed them in the drawable folder, and pulled them into my layout. However, at 128x128 they are huge and apparently cannot be resized. to make them any smaller. Does anyone have any ideas as to what sizes the radio buttons need to be?

Comment: ... at which screen density?

Comment: Hdpi, but i plan on trying to make a version for all screen densities

Comment: follow this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: **32dp** seems to be the standard. So, **48x48px at hdpi**.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find the info or can you just post all the sizes or the conversion please